# R- dataframe with vector entries of different length

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this

```
[1] "NNNNNNNNNN"     "NN NN NN NN NN" "NN NN NN NN NN" "N NN NNN NN NN"
 [5] "NNNNNNNNNNNN"   "NNN NNN NNN"    "NN-NNNNNNN"     "NNNNNNN"       
 [9] "NNNNNNN"        "NNNNNNN"
```

The vector is coded as numbers further on in the code to look like this

```
[[1]]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[[2]]
 [1] 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2

[[3]]
 [1] 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2

[[4]]
 [1] 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2

[[5]]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[[6]]
 [1] 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2
```

It is actual this vector I need to create a dataframe from so I can transpose it and then use it in regression. When I try and use as.data.frame a get an error message say that lengths vary. Any help greatly appreciated

Here is the output of dput

```
dput(vecs2T)
```

list(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 
2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 
2), c(2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2), 
    c(2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))

This is what I would like the data frame to look like

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  1  1  1  9  1  2  2
2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
4  9  9  9  2  2  2  2  1
5  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
6  1  1  1  9  2  2  2  2
7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I would like the first number from each of the vectors to be under V1. So each row corresponds to one of the vectors in dput above. But because the vectors are of different length some of the columns will be empty which seem to be causing the trouble.

Comment: The error is being caused by something else about your code that you haven't shared with us. `as.data.frame` won't care about the lengths of each individual string in a single vector. It's complaining because the different vectors you've given it are different lengths. A data frame must have all columns be the same length. You'll need to share a more complete reproducible example for anyone to help more.

Comment: Welcome to SO Sarah. Why do you want to create a data.frame? Maybe a list is more suitable for your data?

Comment: What do you want your data frame to look like? And can you share `dput(head(your_vector))` so we can see it's structure?

Comment: Not sure of the problem. To me it works.

    `vector <- c("NNNNNNNNNN","NN NN NN NN NN", "NN NN NN NN NN" ,"N NN NNN NN NN", "NNNNNNNNNNNN","NNN NNN NNN"   , "NN-NNNNNNN",     "NNNNNNN", "NNNNNNN"      ,"NNNNNNN")
    as.data.frame(vector)`

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(vector)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(vector))`.

Comment: Thanks for showing the structure - that's actually a *list of vectors* not a single vector you've got there. Now can you show what you want the data frame to look like? Do each of your vectors correspond to a row? A column? Something else? Since data frames are rectangular, what do you want to do when there are different lengths? Fill in with `NA`? Something else?